# reading file contents in C, keeping track of new lines

Tags: c, scanf, stdio, file-pointer

I am reading strings in from a data file in C using `fscanf()` using a loop that goes until `EOF`. The data file contains strings separated by any white space. As the strings are read in with `fscanf()` they will be checked for any invalid information. I need to keep track of the line numbers that an item is on so that if an invalid item is detected the line number of that item will be displayed. Like I said though, the data file is not just one string per line. Is there anything more elegant than reading in everything up to a new line, splitting that into individual strings, and checking those strings? Can I determine the line number where the file pointer is currently pointing?

Answer (score 3):

There is no line number counter in the C I/O libraries. You need to keep track of the line number yourself.

I suggest that you read one line at a time using `fgets`, incrementing your line number counter each time, and then read items from that string using `sscanf`.

Comment: Note that `fgets` may read partial lines if the buffer provided is not long enough, defeating both your validation process and the line counting scheme.  You can detect this by checking the presence of a final `'\n'` at the end of the buffer and reallocate the buffer on such detected partial reads. The non-standard `getline` function will do that for you, check if your environment provides it.